# Lock html table headers when table is set to 100% width

Tags: html, css

ALl of the solutions for this seeingly simple problem involve tables with set defined cell widths. My table is set to be 100% of the width of the screen. Any ideas? I have tried to position:fixed on the thead as well as display:block on the thead and tbody with a scrollible tbody. The problem I have is the thead cells collapse.

- the table may have up 1 - 3 th cells, each could have a colspan of 1 - 5 (not all will be the same)
- I cannot define set td or th widths as I do not know how many cells I
  will have until after the data loads
- I cannot have horizontal
  scrolling

Not sure how to do this...

**HTML**

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Test 1 (should be 50%)</th>
            <th colspan="2">Test 2 (should be 50%)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>A 1 (should be 50%)</td>
            <td>A 2b (should be 25%)</td>
            <td>A 2b (should be 25%)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>B 1</td>
            <td>B 2b</td>
            <td>B 2b</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>C 1</td>
            <td>C 2b</td>
            <td>C 2b</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>D 1</td>
            <td>D 2b</td>
            <td>D 2b</td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>E 1</td>
            <td>E 2b</td>
            <td>E 2b</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table {width:100%;}
thead, tbody {display:block;}
tbody {overflow-x:scroll;height:100px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6pBhP/

Comment: they are fixed. whats the issue?

Comment: removing the display:block removes the scrolling on the tbody. I need the table height to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this styles:

```
thead, tbody {display:block;}
tbody {overflow:scroll;height:100px;}
```

If you want the tbody make scroll, you can stay with tbody style:

```
tbody {overflow:scroll;height:100px;}
```

Comment: ahh... here is the caveat I may have not made clear. I do not know the width of the cells until after the table loads. I cannot set the th or td widths in the css like this. The solution you have is the way that the resources I have found explain it... to define cell widths. I cannot have horizontal scrolling either.